# Is a postincrement always done before a function call?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Consider this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int g=3;

static int foo(int a)
{ 
  return g+a; 
}

int main(void)
{
  printf("%i\n",foo(g++));
}
```

Is the output always 7 (assuming `printf()` will not fail)? Meaning, does the standard guarantee that the expression `g++`, inside the argument list for `foo()`, is executed before `foo()` is entered?  Or is it possible that the compiler sets `g=3` calls `foo()` with `g==3` and increment `g` after the execution of `foo()` is done (and outputs `6` instead of `7`)?

All the compiler (versions) i tests print `7` and didn't show any warnings. But that doesn't mean it has to be that way.

Comment: The expression `foo(g++)` is somewhat equivalent to `int old_value = g; g += 1; foo(old_value);`. That is guaranteed by the specification. If you want answers with quotes from the specification then please add the `language-lawyer` tag. Otherwise [this evaluation order reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order) might be a helpful (if a bit hard) read.

Comment: @jarmod Microsoft might not be the best reference to language-lawyer tagged question, considering the track record with their C compiler.

Comment: @user694733 ah, fair comment. I see the language-lawyer tag was added at some point after the question was asked.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As stated [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order):

> 1. There is a sequence point after the evaluation of all function arguments and of the function designator, and before the actual function call.

This guarantees that `g++` is completed, including incrementing `g` before the function is called.

So, yes, the result `7` is guaranteed and well defined.

**Update**: The C17 standard states this directly in the first sentence of §6.5.2.2-10:

> There is a sequence point after the evaluations of the function designator and the actual arguments
> but before the actual call. Every evaluation in the calling function (including other function calls)
> that is not otherwise specifically sequenced before or after the execution of the body of the called
> function is indeterminately sequenced with respect to the execution of the called function

Comment: It may be worth noting, though it's not relevant to the particular question, that an operation which is "indeterminately sequenced" with regard to the execution of the called function will either be sequenced completely before the execution of the function, or completely after it.